# Append entries to an existing \graphicspath

Tags: graphics

I have a \graphicspath command at the beginning of a document (the main document):

```
\graphicspath{{images/}{extras/images/}}
```

I have sub-documents into which I insert images (actually SVG files from Inkscape):

```
\def\svgwidth{\linewidth}
\input{/another/path/images/ppn522-graphs.pdf_tex}
```

These sub-documents may be inserted into different main documents.

But they need some information about images to be included so I need to do this:

```
\def\svgwidth{\linewidth}
\graphicspath{{/another/path/images/}}
\input{/another/path/images/ppn522-graphs.pdf_tex}
```

Problem: this overrides my first \graphicspath declaration: my logo images (and extras/images) are not found anymore (generating errors) after I insert the \graphicspath{{/another/path/images/}}

My question: how could I append an entry to the \graphicspath ?

Or is there a variable that contains the \graphicspath value so I can re-use it ?

```
    \graphicspath{\thegraphicspathvalue{/another/path/images/}}
```

EDIT: I already tried this, but it does not work :

```
\graphicspath{\typeout{\Ginput@path}{../images/}}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The variable containing the paths is `\Ginput@path`, so you can define

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\appendtographicspath[1]{%
  \g@addto@macro\Ginput@path{#1}%
}
\makeatother
```

and `\appendtographicspath{{../images/}}` should do. Remember the braces around the path; you can add several paths.

This addition is global. You might want to extend the macro for “prepending”; in this case, use `etoolbox`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\appendtographicspath[1]{%
  \gappto\Ginput@path{#1}%
}
\newcommand\prependtographicspath[1]{%
  \gpreto\Ginput@path{#1}%
}
\makeatother
```

With `\appto` and `\preto` the additions would be local, but I don't think it's good.

#### Update 2022

Time has come for an update. The macro `\Ginput@path` behaves like an `expl3` token list variable.

We can therefore use `expl3` for a more flexible approach (also prompted by a comment).

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\appendtographicspath}{m}
 {
  \tl_if_exist:cF { Ginput@path } { \tl_new:c { Ginput@path } }
  \tl_gput_right:cn {Ginput@path} { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\prependtographicspath}{m}
 {
  \tl_if_exist:cF { Ginput@path } { \tl_new:c { Ginput@path } }
  \tl_gput_left:cn {Ginput@path} { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Something like

```
\appendtographicspath{{a}{b}{c}}
```

will append all three items.

If one wants to allow specifying the items to append as a comma separated list, then do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\appendtographicspath}{m}
 {
  \tl_if_exist:cF { Ginput@path } { \tl_new:c { Ginput@path } }
  \clist_map_function:nN { #1 } \steven_gpath_append:n
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \steven_gpath_append:n
 {
  \tl_gput_right:cn { Ginput@path } { {#1} }
 }

% for debugging

\NewDocumentCommand{\showgraphicspath}{}{\tl_show:c { Ginput@path }}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\graphicspath{{a}{b}{c}}

\appendtographicspath{{d},{e}}

\showgraphicspath

\appendtographicspath{f,g}

\showgraphicspath
```

Braces would be stripped off by `\clist_map_inline:nN` so we can reinsert them.

At the end of the job, as witnessed by `\showgraphicspath`, you'd get

```
\Ginput@path={a}{b}{c}{d}{e}{f}{g}
```

Comment: I works perfectly. A question: the order is important only if I have several images with the same name, isn't it ?

Comment: @lauhub Yes. Note that using `\graphicspath` slows down the searching process, so more often visited directories should go first.

Comment: Hi @egreg, thanks for this solution! Can I ask you a follow-up question? I'd like to append to the graphics path using a for-loop, looping over a comma-separated list of paths using `\@for`. This gives me an `undefined control sequence. \p -> \@nil` error. I suspect that it literally attempts to add `\p/Images` to the graphics path. I'm stuck from here. Any ideas?

Comment: @Steven Why don't you just do `\appendtographicspath{{a}{b}{c}}`? Don't use backslashes for paths on Windows; TeX distributions recognize `/` instead.

Comment: @egreg because I want to let the user set a (comma-separated) list, so I use `\@for\p:=\thelist\do{...}`. Turns out the answer is to use `\expandafter\appendtographicspath\expandafter{\expandafter{\p/Images}}`, but thanks anyway!

Comment: @Steven Look at the update.

Comment: @egreg thanks for taking the time! Though, I should've mentioned that I intended to do more with each path in the for-loop; I'd first define a comma-separated list, then loop over each item in the list to add it to the graphics path and then do some more with the path. Otherwise, your original solution already worked perfectly, i.e. using the braces.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, `\appendtographicspath` assumes that `\graphicspath` was set earlier. Not sure how commendable this is, but adding `\graphicspath{}` immediately after `\usepackage{graphicx}` fixed some errors I had while compiling.

Comment: @PatrickT Which implementation are you referring to?

Comment: Both the first one and the post-2022 versions were giving me errors (different messages). I used the above code for years without problems, until today. I did update my `texlive` packages. Maybe just a temporary issue on my system... Thanks for sharing so much great code egreg!

Comment: @PatrickT I added the checks for the post 2022 versions.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot egreg!