# How to append the graphics path in a for-loop?

Tags: graphics, loops, comma-separated-list

## Objective

I wanted to create a command that enables me to add a collection of paths in a comma-separated list to my graphics path, next to a bunch of other instructions for each path that I will not include.
To append the graphics path, I use the code written by @egreg, see [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/171591/177841).
The result is `\setDependentPaths`, see the MWE below.

## Issue

In the MWE, I placed an image `image.png` in the relative folder `mypath/Resources/Images`. So, I want to add `mypath` as a 'dependent path'. If I compile the document with the `\includegraphics` command commented out, it does not produce an error. When I don't comment it out, it produces the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\p ->\@nil
```

I suspect that the loop variable `\p` is used literally, such that `\p/Resources/Images` is used as the graphics path instead of `mypath/Resources/Images`. However, I'm not sure, and even if that's the case, I don't know how to solve it.

Anyone any clues?

## MWE

```
\documentclass{book}

% Load packages
\usepackage{graphicx}

% Set graphics path
\graphicspath{
    {Resources/Images/}
}

% Enable appending to graphics path
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\appendGraphicsPath}[1]{%
    \g@addto@macro\Ginput@path{#1}%
}
\makeatother

% This command loops over a comma-separated list to add graphics paths
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\setDependentPaths}[1]{%
    \@for\p:=#1\do{%
        \appendGraphicsPath{{\p/Resources/Images/}}%
    }%
}
\makeatother

% Set the paths that my document depends on
\setDependentPaths{mypath,anotherpath}

\begin{document}

A title

\includegraphics{image.png}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to expand `\p` so

```
\expandafter\appendGraphicsPath\expandafter{\expandafter{\p
```

Comment: I knew it, I need more knowledge on expansion! Would you be so kind to add an explanation on why you placed `\expandafter` in those locations?

Comment: @Steven the first `\expandafter ` expands the second, the second expands the third, and the third expands `\p` after which the input buffer looks like `\appendGraphicsPath{{mypath`

Comment: by any chance, do you know how to do in case I do `\providecommand{\main}{.}` and call `\appendGraphicsPath{{\main/\p/Resources/Images/}}` in the for loop?